# Does piecewise differentiable curve mean $C^1$-curve in this context?

Tags: complex-analysis

Munkres - Topology p.405

> Lemma 66.3
>
> Let $\gamma$ be a piecewise differentiable loop in the complex plane; let $a$ be a point not in the image of $f$. Then, $Wnd(\gamma,a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{1}{z-a} dz$.
>
> Theorem 66.4 (Ahlfors version)
>
> Let $C$ be a simple closed piecewise differentiable curve in the complex plane. Let $G$ be the interior of $C$. If $f$ is analytic on an open set $\Omega$ containing $G$ and $C$, then for each point $a$ in $G$, $F(a)=±\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{F(z)}{z-a} dz$

Munkres wrote that this version of Cauchy integral formula is in Ahlfors's text, but Ahlfors, in his text, defines a "piecewise differentiable curve" as a piecewise $C^1$ curve.

Nevertheless, does this theorem hold for a loop which is piecewise differentiable but not piecewise $C^1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem is even true for rectifiable curves (but this takes quite some effort; even defining what the integral is takes some work).

In most situations, the exact formulation doesn't matter all that much. Recifiable, piecewise differentiable curves can be approximated well enough with piecewise $C^1$-curves for example.

You want to exclude some pathological examples though: a closed loop which is piecewise differentiable doesn't have to be rectifiable. A piece of the curve could be the parts of the graph $y=x^2 \sin (1/x^4)$ (or similar) and it's not clear how to define curve integrals along such beasts.

Comment: Is there a text or a page proving this for rectifiable curves? I can define Riemann-Stieltjes integral along bounded variation, and I'll try to prove this for non-differentiable rectifiable curves, but I need a reference so that I can check when I get stuck proving it.

Comment: @Rubertos The most general treatment I have seen in print is in Tutschke, Vasudeva: [An Introduction to Complex Analysis: Classical and Modern Approaches](https://books.google.se/books?id=puXBwu7ztkwC&pg=PR6&lpg=PR6&dq=tutschke+vasudeva&source=bl&ots=Jmsi5OqIhP&sig=VE9H5vuJDxmZkVv2pXCqrT9E3Yg&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBGoVChMIodT9-fv4xwIVSd0sCh23bQ43#v=onepage&q=tutschke%20vasudeva&f=false) The "introduction" in the title is a little misleading, since it's a good idea to have seen measure theory and functional analysis before trying to read it. (Section 4.6.3 seems relevant for your question.)